# Creating a daily report

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Query:

```
select 
    Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Cold Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ColdCall,
    Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Referral Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As ReferalCall,
    Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Email Sent & Fax Sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Email Sent & Fax Sent]
from 
    tbl_event 
where
    (fld_event_created_on >= '12/15/2015 12:00:00 AM' 
     and fld_event_created_on <= '12/16/2015 3:53:04 AM')
```

Questions:

- How to display timings column in { I will take from hour, to hour }
- How to add start hour (in from hour field) as 5:30PM?
- How to get end hour (in to hour field) as 6:30PM?
- How to increase hours in table automatically?

For example:

```
5:30PM to 6:30PM
6:30PM to 7:30PM
::
::
4:30AM to 5:30 AM
```

Comment: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/how-to-schedule-sql-query-to-run-in-microsoft-sql-server/ ?

Comment: Add your table structure

Comment: Use as tag only DBMS you want to use (no all SQL Server versions!)

Comment: SQL Server?  What not use SSRS?  Or you could use SQLCMD and pipe out to a CSV..  SSRS, you can output the results to a number of different formats..

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution for you. It is not the simplest, but also allows irregular time spans:

```
-- drop table CallLog
create table CallLog
(
    CallLogId INT,
    Timestamp DATETIME2,
    Subject VARCHAR(100),
    OnlyTime AS CAST(Timestamp AS TIME)
)

-- drop table TimeInterval
create table TimeInterval
(
    TimeIntervalId INT,
    StartTime TIME,
    EndTime TIME,
    -- to handle case when interval is split between days
    CrossesMidnight BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_TimeInterval_CrossesMidnight DEFAULT(0)
) 

insert into TimeInterval values (1, '23:30', '00:30', 1)
insert into TimeInterval values (1, '00:30', '01:30', 0)
insert into TimeInterval values (1, '01:30', '02:30', 0)
insert into TimeInterval values (1, '02:30', '20:30', 0)
insert into TimeInterval values (1, '20:30', '21:30', 0)
insert into TimeInterval values (1, '21:30', '22:30', 0)
insert into TimeInterval values (1, '22:30', '23:30', 0)
go

select * from TimeInterval

insert into CallLog values (1, '2015-01-01 10:00', 'Cold Call') 
insert into CallLog values (1, '2015-01-01 23:35', 'Cold Call') 
insert into CallLog values (1, '2015-01-02 00:01', 'Referral Call') 
insert into CallLog values (1, '2015-01-02 10:01', 'Referral Call') 
insert into CallLog values (1, '2015-01-02 21:35', 'Referral Call') 
select * from CallLog

-- I did not find an universal formatting function to also work only on TIMEs
alter function dbo.timeFormat(@time TIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, @time) AS VARCHAR) + '.' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, @time) AS VARCHAR)
END
GO

-- join condition is very complex and might need rewriting for very large data (or maybe just get rid of that midnight interval :) )
-- TODO: <= 23:59:59 skips events within the last second in day!
;with cte as (
select 
    t.StartTime, t.EndTime,
    Sum(Case when Subject='Cold Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ColdCall,
    Sum(Case when Subject='Referral Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As ReferalCall
from CallLog l
    join TimeInterval t on
        -- this would greatly simplify, if midnight is not inside the interval
    (t.CrossesMidnight = 0 AND (l.OnlyTime > t.StartTime AND l.OnlyTime <= t.EndTime)) 
    OR 
    (t.CrossesMidnight = 1 AND (((l.OnlyTime > t.StartTime) AND l.OnlyTime <= '23:59:59') OR (l.OnlyTime < t.EndTime)))
GROUP BY t.StartTime, t.EndTime)
select dbo.timeFormat(cte.StartTime) + ' - ' + dbo.timeFormat(cte.EndTime), cte.ColdCall, cte.ReferalCall 
from cte
go
```